# R: extracting lm() attributes

Tags: list, r, lm

I want to extract the fstatistic value from summary(lm()). So far the only way I've found is

```
summary(lm(this_vector ~ that_vector))["fstatistic"][[1]][1]
```

Is there a less verbose way to get that cell value? The question is a bit pedantic but I thought the answer might provide some interesting info on how to use R lists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try either of these:

```
summary(lm(this_vector ~ that_vector))$fstatistic[1]
summary(lm(this_vector ~ that_vector))[["fstatistic"]][1]
```

`["fstatistic"]` returns a list with elements that have names that match what's inside the single brackets, so you need the `[[1]]` to get the first element.  Double brackets return the element itself, as does using the `$` notation.

Answer (score 0):

The package `broom` contains functions to convenietly extract estimates and model fit statistics from various models (among them `lm`). For extracting the F statistic, use `broom`'s `glance()` function. See the example mentioned here https://github.com/dgrtwo/broom.

In your case, that would be

```
glance(lm(this_vector ~ that_vector))$statistic
```